# Run tensorboard to visualise docker container running reinforcement learning in Ray Rllib

Tags: docker, tensorboard

I have a docker container running a custom simulation for reinforcement learning. I have placed all of this code in a docker container.

This code takes a long time to run, and I would like to be able to visualise the algorithm in real time.

However, I am unsure on how to start tensorboard from this container. I was thinking of saving the data to a volume and then accessing that from another container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing as a I proposed, saving the data in a volume and accessing the external data source via tensorboard.

```
docker run -it -v <path/to/tensorflow_data>:</path/to/vol> -v <docker_container>:latest
```

Where code inside `<>` should be replaced with where the tensorflow data is stored, the path where you saved the volume inside the container and the name of your container.

Answer (score 0):

The steps I followed and I could visualise the results with tensorboard:

- when creating a the container, open/map an external port for tensorboard:

> nvidia-docker run -d --name tkra_tensorb --ipc=host -it -p 8513:8090
> **-p 3014:6006** -v /data:/data tkra_tb

- inside the container, run tensorboard:

> tensorboard --logdir /data/tkra/MyDatasets/resnet101/checkpoints/
> --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006

Open tensorboard in my browser: **<server_address>:3014**